# Pandas: transpose df and create multi-index using column names

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multi-index

I have the following df:

```
            user  2019-01-01  2019-01-02  
0             Me         1.0         3.0 
1         Myself         2.0         2.0  
2      And_Irene         3.0         1.0
```

I want to transform this into the following:

```
                        Count                       
2019-01-01  Me          1.0   
2019-01-01  Myself      2.0
2019-01-01  And_Irene   3.0    
2019-01-02  Me          3.0
2019-01-02  Myself      2.0
2019-01-02  And_Irene   1.0
```

I think this has to be done through `df.T`, but I am not sure what the next steps should be. Using `df.T` returns:

```
             0       1          2
user        Me  Myself  And_Irene
2019-01-01   1       2          3
2019-01-02   3       2          1
```

But then, how can I group the results using the column names? I am not sure this is the right way to do this.

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='user')`

Comment: `pd.melt(df,id_vars='user',value_name='count').set_index(['user','variable'])` works